# How to convert two column from dataframe into one list with R

Tags: r, list

I got a dataframe like this

input

```
    ID   RE
    am_A re456
    am_A re4
    am_B re20
    am_C re47 
    am_B re456
    am_C re12
```

And I would like to convert this two column in one list like this :

output :

```
$`am_A`
[1] "re456" "re4"

$`am_B`
[1] "re20" "re456"

$`am_C`
[1] "re47" "re12"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dlply was made for this:

```r
your.data %>% dlply( "ID", `[[`, "RE" )
```

Output:

```
$am_A
[1] "re456" "re4"  

$am_B
[1] "re20"  "re456"

$am_C
[1] "re47" "re12"

attr(,"split_type")
[1] "data.frame"
attr(,"split_labels")
    ID
1 am_A
2 am_B
3 am_C
```

If you don't want those extra attributes there, you can just pipe to c:

```r
data %>% dlply( "ID", `[[`, "RE" ) %>% c
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `split` from base R:

```
split(dat$RE, dat$ID)

# $am_A
# [1] "re456" "re4"  
# 
# $am_B
# [1] "re20"  "re456"
# 
# $am_C
# [1] "re47" "re12"
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    ID = c("am_A", "am_A", "am_B", "am_C", "am_B", "am_C"),
    RE = c("re456", "re4", "re20", "re47", "re456", "re12")
    ),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pivot_wider`, then `unnest`-ing the columns, and finally `as.list` to get a list.

```r
library(tidyverse)

my_df <- tibble::tribble(
      ~ID, ~RE,
  "am_A","re456",
    "am_A","re4",
   "am_B","re20",
   "am_C","re47",
  "am_B","re456",
   "am_C","re12"
  )

my_df %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ID, 
              values_from = RE, 
              values_fn = list) %>%  #to suppress a warning
  unnest(cols = names(.)) %>%        # unnest needs column names now
  as.list()
#> $am_A
#> [1] "re456" "re4"  
#> 
#> $am_B
#> [1] "re20"  "re456"
#> 
#> $am_C
#> [1] "re47" "re12"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>